# Squaring absolute number equation gets error

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-verification, absolute-value

Why if I squared this equation
$$|4x-3|=-|2x-1|$$
it will give a solution of $\frac{2}{3}$ and $1$?

But actually, it has no solution. Why squaring the equation will cause an error?

Comment: Remember than squaring **always** introduces spurious roots.

Comment: Because by squaring we lose informations about the sign

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/568780/why-cant-you-square-both-sides-of-an-equation

Answer (score 2):

1. Because from your equation we have:
   $$4x-3=2x-1=0,$$
   which is impossible.
2. Because $a=b\Leftrightarrow a^2=b^2$ is wrong.

The counterexample is your equation. Also, for example. $-1=1$ is wrong, but $(-1)^2=1^2$ is true.

Answer (score 2):

Try to substitute thsoe values inside to see what is going on

if you substitute $x=1$. you get $LHS=1$, $RHS=-1$, clearly $1 \neq -1$ but $1^2=(-1)^2$.

You can still use squaring to obtain possible solutions, however, you have to check whether they still satisfy the original problem.

Answer (score 0):

Squaring both sides and solving for $x$ is like solving $f(|4x-3|)=f(-|2x-1|)$ where $f(x)=x^2.$ This may yield an extraneous "solution" since $f(x)=x^2$ isn't one-to-one i.e. $$f(|4x-3|)=f(-|2x-1|) \nrightarrow |4x-3|=-|2x-1|.$$ If you seek to obtain an equation with the same solution set as the original, make sure you're working with one-to-one functions.