# Is this a valid way to prove that $x > 4$ $\Rightarrow$ $x^2 > 9$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$x > 4$

$\rightarrow$ $x - 1 > 3$

$\rightarrow$ $(x - 1)^2 > 9$
 and obviously if $(x - 1)^2 > 9$ then $x^2 > 9$

Comment: See: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/568780/why-cant-you-square-both-sides-of-an-equation

Comment: It's not true that $(x-1)^{2}>9$ implies that $x^{2}>9$.  For example, if $x=-2.5$, then $(x-1)^{2}>9$ but $x^{2}<9$.

Comment: @BrianBorchers $x>4$ from the start.

Comment: I guess somewhere you need to use that $x>0$ in an essential way.

Answer (score 5):

Why don't you use
$$x>4\implies x^2>16>9$$

Note: How did we arrive at the second step from the first one?

Comment: Oh that's probably better haha. But does mine make sense at least? Like if I used it on an exam would I get full marks?

Comment: @ming Your argument is also correct however to be on the safe side in an exam, you should write that *"...since,we know, $x^2$ is an increasing function, hence the result follows..."*. You should explicitly mention that $x^2$ is an increasing function.

Answer (score 0):

There are two underlying facts in what you label as "obvious" in your last step.

$x-1>3 \implies x-1>0$.

$x>x-1$ (this one is universal) and $x-1>0 \implies x^2>(x-1)^2$.

But of course the fastest way is as Andrés Mejía and tatan suggested.