# If $x=3-2\sqrt{2}$, find $\sqrt{x}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$. Two methods give two answers ($-2$ vs $\pm2$).

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Given $x=3-2\sqrt{2}$ find value of $\sqrt{x}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$

---

**Method 1.**

Let $$\sqrt{x}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}=t \tag{1}$$

Squaring both sides we get
$$t^2=x+\frac{1}{x}-2=(3+2\sqrt{2})+(3-2\sqrt{2})-2=4 \tag{2}$$
So $$t=\pm 2 \tag{3}$$

---

**Method 2.**

$$\sqrt{x}=\sqrt{3-2\sqrt{2}}=\sqrt{2}-1 \tag{4}$$

So $$\sqrt{x}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}=\sqrt{2}-1-(\sqrt{2}+1)=-2 \tag{5}$$

---

> What is correct?

Comment: What value has $x = 1+1$? Squaring gives $x^2 = (1+1)^2 = 1 + 2 + 1 = 4$. So $x = \pm 2$?

Comment: Both are correct. Method $1$ just gives less, i.e., only $t^2=4$, which is correct.

Comment: Aside from what everyone else has mentioned, it is also worth noting that you have an expression entirely in terms of a constant $x$. That expression could only have one value. Imagine if $\sqrt x - 1/\sqrt x$ had two values instead. Then

$$-2 = \sqrt x - \frac 1 {\sqrt x} = 2$$

but $2 \ne -2$ obviously.

Comment: $t^2 = 4 \implies t = \pm 2$ means $t$ can be one of $+2$ or $-2$. It doesn't force $t$ to $+2$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't you square both sides of an equation?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/568780/why-cant-you-square-both-sides-of-an-equation)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $x=3-2\sqrt 2 \lt 1, \sqrt x \lt 1$. (the square root function is increasing) This means $\frac{1}{\sqrt x} \gt 1 \gt \sqrt x$ and so $$\sqrt x - \frac{1}{\sqrt x} \lt 0$$

Answer (score 3):

Method $2$ is correct.  In method $1$, you introduced an extraneous solution when you squared both sides.

For example, $x=1\implies x^2=1\implies x=\pm1$, but the implication doesn’t work in reverse.

Answer (score 2):

Squaring will lose the information about the sign, see [Why can't you square both sides of an equation?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/568780/318073).

(P.S. You can check your results in [wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sqrt%283-2sqrt%282%29%29-1%2Fsqrt%283-2sqrt%282%29%29).)