# Solving for $x$ in $0 = 2e^{-x}\big(\sin(x) + 2\cos(x)\big)$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have the following equation:

$$0 = 2e^{-x}\big(\sin(x) + 2\cos(x)\big),~x\in[0,3]$$

I must find the value of $x$ within the interval $[0,3]$.

Here is my work so far:

\begin{align}
0 &= 2e^{-x}\big(\sin(x) + 2\cos(x)\big)\newline
&= \sin(x) + 2\cos(x) && \gets\text{factored out }2e^{-x}\text{ because }e^{-x}\overset{!}{\neq}0\text{ …}\newline
2\cos(x) &= -\sin(x)\newline
2\cos(x) &= -\sqrt{1 - \cos^2(x)} && \gets\text{given the Pythagorean trig identities…}\newline
4\cos^2(x) &= 1 - \cos^2(x)\newline
5\cos^2(x) &= 1\newline
\cos^2(x) &= \frac{1}{5}\newline
\cos(x) &= \pm\sqrt{\frac{1}{5}}\newline
x &= \cos^{-1}\left(\pm\sqrt{\frac{1}{5}}\right)\text{, }x\in[0,3]\newline
&\approx 1.11,\text{ }2.03
\end{align}

The real answer, as I could confirm with an online graphing calculator, is $x = 2.03$. However, $\cos^{-1}\left(+\sqrt{\frac{1}{5}}\right)$ also equals $\approx1.11$, although that solution seems to not be real, according to the graphing calculator.

Additionally, the answer key for the homework I am working on makes it obvious that $2.03$ is the only answer. (This is part of a bigger problem, but plugging $2.03$ into the next step results in what the answer key wants, and $1.11$ does not work.)

My question is as follows: How do I confirm algebraically that $1.11$ is not a real solution? If it weren't for any of the external sources that I used, I couldn't figure this out by myself, as far as my knowledge/intuition goes (as of now).

**Note.** In the above equation environment, I am using $\overset!\neq$ as "cannot equal".

Comment: From $2\cos(x) = -\sin(x)$, you can infer $2=-\sin(x)/\cos(x)=-\tan(x)$

Comment: Common error, squaring is not an equivalent operation and hence can introduce extraneous solutions (but you won't lose any). Simply checking the original equation is enough to find which ones are not solutions. See also [Why can't you square both sides of an equation?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/568780) and linked posts.

Comment: @Sil Ah yes, checking the original equation. Thanks!

Comment: We can also use $e^{-x}>0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I had to guess, it is because of "information loss" when you squared both sides in the step
$$
2\cos(x) = -\sqrt{1 - \cos^2(x)}
\;\;\;\xrightarrow{\;\;\;\text{square}\;\;\;}\;\;\;
4\cos^2(x) = 1 - \cos^2(x)
$$
Suppose that $\cos(x)$ were positive; then the first equality wouldn't hold ($-\sqrt x \le 0$), but the second one still could.

One notes that $\arccos(\sqrt{1/5})$ gives $2/\sqrt{5}$ on the first expression, and $-2/\sqrt 5$ on the second expression, confirming my suspicions.

---

In case you're confused about this "information loss", a simpler example occurs with solving $x=1$. While trivial (the solution is obvious), if we for some reason squared both sides, we get $x^2 = 1$, which now has $x=-1$ as an extraneous solution.

In general, if you apply an operation to both sides which is not "injective" (which means it can send different values to the same value, just as how $f(x) = x^2$ has $f(-1) = f(1)$ even though $-1 \ne 1$), this phenomenon can happen.

---

Of course, if one merely wishes to confirm that $\arccos(\sqrt{1/5})$ is not a real solution to the equation (in the sense of "real" meaning a "true" solution), one need only plug it in into the original equation they wished to solve.

For the original equation, [Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=2+e%5E%28-x%29+%5B+sin%28x%29+%2B+2+cos%28x%29+%5D+when+x+%3D+arccos%281%2Fsqrt%285%29%29) returns the value
$$
\frac{8}{\sqrt 5} e^{-\arccos(1/\sqrt 5)} \approx 1.18
$$
which is decisively nonzero. However, $\arccos(-1/\sqrt 5)$ does return zero ([Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=2+e%5E%28-x%29+%5B+sin%28x%29+%2B+2+cos%28x%29+%5D+when+x+%3D+arccos%28-1%2Fsqrt%285%29%29)).

Comment: Thank you for your very educative answer, I appreciate your time. God bless.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative

$$\sin(x) + 2\cos(x) =\sqrt 5 \sin\left(x+\arctan 2\right)=0$$

which requires

$$x=-\arctan 2 +\pi\approx 2.03$$

which indeed, as suggested in the comments, corresponds to the solution we can obtain by the simpler way (for $\cos x \neq 0$)

$$\sin(x) + 2\cos(x)=0 \iff \tan x = -2$$

By these methods we avoid possible extraneous solutions introduced by squaring the original equation.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply test if $\arccos(\sqrt{1/5})$ is a solution directly:

$$\begin{align}
0&\stackrel{?}{=}\sin(\arccos(\sqrt{1/5}))+2\cos(\arccos(\sqrt{1/5}))\\
0&\stackrel{?}{=}\frac{\sqrt{5-1}}{\sqrt{5}}+2\sqrt{\frac15}\\
0&\stackrel{\text{no}}{=}\frac{4}{\sqrt{5}}
\end{align}
$$

That is how you can establish that potential solution is in fact extraneous without using any calculator.

And you can likewise verify that $\arccos(-\sqrt{1/5})$ works.