# Can you square both sides in a proof?

Tags: inequality, radicals

Like say we had to prove that $\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3} < \sqrt{26}$. Could you square both sides to prove it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are some common pitfalls when squaring both sides of an equation?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/445585/what-are-some-common-pitfalls-when-squaring-both-sides-of-an-equation)

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can, since both numbers are non-negative. That is, if $a,b\in[0,\infty)$, then $a<b\iff a^2<b^2$.

Comment: Yeah but isn’t it that we don’t really know if $a<b$ in the first place, cuz that’s what we’re trying to prove? So how would we know that $a^2<b^2$? Would you have to do like a proof by contradiction instead and assume that it’s greater than or equal to $sqrt26$, and then square it/show the negation leads to a contradiction?

Comment: @gughy The implication is both ways here if the terms are non-negative. That means if you prove it for the squares it is true for the square roots - which is what you want.

Comment: @gughy No. You do it as follows:\begin{align}\sqrt2+\sqrt3<\sqrt{26}&\iff\left(\sqrt2+\sqrt3\right)^2<26\\&\iff2+3+2\sqrt6<26\\&\iff2\sqrt6<21.\end{align}Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 6):

We have: $\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3} < 2\sqrt{3} = \sqrt{12} < \sqrt{26}$. That's probably faster.

Comment: Probably, but it doesn't address OP's immediate concern. :)

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on José Carlos Santos's answer:  yes, in this case, but not generally.  He shows the "yes, in this case" part.  Generally, however, signs matter.  From the true statement $-1 < 1$, squaring both sides seems to give $1 \overset{?}{<} 1$, which is not true.

Answer (score 0):

In general, if $f(x)$ is any strictly increasing function over any interval $I = (a,b)$ (or $[a,b), (a,\infty), (-\infty,b),...$), then for any $u,v \in I$, $u < v \iff f(u) < f(v)$.

Taking square $x \mapsto x^2$ and square roots $x \mapsto \sqrt{x}$ are strictly increasing functions over $[0,\infty)$. So for any non-negative $u, v$, you have 
$$u < v \iff u^2 < v^2 \iff \sqrt{u} < \sqrt{v}$$

For your case, you know both sides are non-negative.
This means
$$\begin{align} & \sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3} \stackrel{?}{<} \sqrt{26}\\
\iff & 5 + 2\sqrt{6} = (\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})^2 \stackrel{?}{<} 26\\
\iff & 2\sqrt{6} \stackrel{?}{<} 21\\
\iff & 24 = (2\sqrt{6})^2 < 21^2 = 441
\end{align}
$$
Since you know the last inequality is true, the inequality you want to show $\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3} < \sqrt{26}$ is also true.